# Pandas script getting stuck on Unix server, but not on Windows

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply

I have written a Pandas script, applying a mathematical function to each row in a Pandas dataframe, as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

numbers = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep="\t", header=None)

combinations = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2], sep=" ", header=None)

pop = int(int(sys.argv[4]) + 5)

def score_freq(line):
    score=0
    freq=1
    for j in range(len(line)):
        if line[j][1] != numbers.values[j][1]:   # homozygous for ref
            score+=0
            freq*=(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop]))*float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop])))
        elif line[j][0] != numbers.values[j][1] and line[j][1] == numbers.values[j][1]: # heterozygous
            score+=(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(2*(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop]))*float(numbers.values[j][pop])))
        elif line[j][0] == numbers.values[j][1]:
            score+=2*(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(float(numbers.values[j][pop])*float(numbers.values[j][pop]))

        if freq < sys.argv[3]:   # threshold to stop loop in interest of efficiency 
            break

    return pd.Series([score, freq])

combinations[['score', 'freq']] = combinations.apply(lambda row: score_freq(row), axis=1)

combinations.to_csv(sys.argv[5], index=False, header=False)
```

The input file for 'numbers' is as such:

```
SNP1             A       T       1.25    0.223143551314     0.97273 
SNP2             C       G       1.07    0.0676586484738    0.3     
SNP3             T       A       1.08    0.0769610411361    0.1136
```

While the input for 'combinations' is as such:

```
    AA   CC   TT
    AT   CC   TT
    TT   CC   TT
    AA   CG   TT
    AT   CG   TT
    TT   CG   TT
    AA   GG   TT
    AT   GG   TT
    TT   GG   TT
    AA   CC   TA
    AT   CC   TA
    TT   CC   TA
    AA   CG   TA
    AT   CG   TA
    TT   CG   TA
    AA   GG   TA
    AT   GG   TA
    TT   GG   TA
    AA   CC   AA
    AT   CC   AA
    TT   CC   AA
    AA   CG   AA
    AT   CG   AA
    TT   CG   AA
    AA   GG   AA
    AT   GG   AA
    TT   GG   AA
```

The 'pop' variable is to handle additional columns that may be present in the 'numbers' input table, as additional columns would represent frequencies for additional groups.

The issue I am having here is that when running my script in Windows, it takes less than a second, but it is getting stuck when running it on my Unix server. I have let the program run for over 30 minutes, but it is not completing.

The most recent call is :

```
combinations[['score', 'freq']] = combinations.apply(lambda row: score_freq(row), axis=1)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you able to use some print statements (or debugger in IDE) to track the progress of the program itself?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I just tried adding a print statement 'print (score,freq)', in my main function, and it seems that it is constantly returning the same results. Could the apply function be looping the same line over and over again? It worked perfectly fine in Windows though..